# Black rendered images with Cycler and Blender Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

I'm trying to fallow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYemC0j6Ag) tutorial, but I am only rendering black images (or videos).
I only have downloaded the file and tried to render with Blender 2.74 on MacOSX and Blender 2.76 on Windows 7 (and also old versions of blender).
I already checked lights, camera, layers and scene. I also tried both Cycles and Blender Render.

I cannot find the problem!

Comment: See if one of these other questions helps you. [Render turns black when finished](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14377/2217), [Why objects render black](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10611/2217), [Rendering and materials are black](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19489/2217), and [Why are the renderlayers rendering black?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39527/2217). If none of these solve your problem, then you will need to add more info to your question, and probably a blend file.

Comment: Thanks @David! 

To solve the problem I modified the compositer in Compositing panel.
There were some options for the lens and for the post-processing.