# Emission object renders black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Inside the barrel of the gun is an object emitting a gradient (purple - teal) light.  You can see the light is being emitted, but the object itself is black.  How do I get the object to render with the material I've applied to it?

Things I've tried:

1. [Clicked on the camera icon right of 'UVMap_final' to activate it as the UV map for rendering.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10611/why-are-objects-rendering-black-even-with-texture-both-cycles-and-bi)
2. [Disabled auto smooth under Object Data -> UV Maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10611/why-are-objects-rendering-black-even-with-texture-both-cycles-and-bi)
3. Checked to make sure the layer is set to be rendered and isn't masked.
4. Added a hemi light above the object (although this shouldn't matter, the only object rendering black is one that I have set to emit light).

I feel as though this could have something to do with my node cycle settings (or lack thereof):

[image: Node Cycle Settings]

Here are close-ups of the object in "Materials" view and also in rendered view so you can see more clearly what I mean when I say the object is black:

[image: Materials view the object is visible and has the correct gradient texture]

[image: Here is a close-up of the object just inside the barrel of the gun. You can see it is pitch black, but still emits light...]

Per request below is a screenshot of what the Gun.001 materials node setup looks like:

[image: Gun.001 materials node setup]

Comment: I tried your node setup on a sphere, and it works without issues. And looking closely at your screenshot, there definitely is a hint of that gradient inside the barrel of your gun.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley I added two screenshots to better illustrate the problem, close-up.

Comment: What does the Gun.001 material node setup look like?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the Gun.001 material node setup to the bottom of the post @Adam

Comment: I see you are using images with UV mapping. What method did you use to unwrap the gun?

Comment: The gun is a separate object completely.  I can even copy & paste a basic object with the same exact material settings as the heart object which is rendering black, and it renders as intended (with the purple/teal gradient emission).  I have even tried copy & pasting the material from that object which works, and apply it to the heart, yet it still renders black.

As for the gun the UV unwrapping method used I'm unsure as I didn't create the gun.  I believe it was done manually because it looks perfect.

Comment: I've been testing things out and it looks as though the problem originates from the fact that my 3D obj files were exported from Photoshop, which has multiple sides.  When I deleted several of the materials (except for one), the black render was the result.  I'm looking for a method of simplifying the exported object & materials from photoshop (so I can use ONE material for this object in blender) before I answer.

Comment: The displacement of the gun may be the culprit here. The output of the normal map is a vector, and the displacement socket of the material expects a scalar (i.e. a single number). If you connect a vector to it, you'll get that vector's magnitude, without accounting for its direction. This displacement may occlude the heart bullet. Could you try to connect the normal map output to the **Normal** input of both the glossy and the diffuse shader, and quite possibly lower the strength.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley it's something else.  It has to do with how Photoshop exports multi-faceted objects.  When I re-imported the original OBJ with all "sides"/"facets" (Front Inflation, Front Bevel, Extrusion, Back Bevel, Back Inflation) it works like a charm.

Now I just need to figure out how to merge these into a single coherent object as if they were made in Blender so I don't have to manage 5 different materials for one object...

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem originated from deleting the extra materials that came with the exported Waveform (.obj) from Photoshop.  I believe this is a unique problem, probably different from the other "help my object(s) render all black" found around here.

To fix this I simply re-imported the original object and left all 5 materials that came with the object.  It's not an ideal solution for me because I would prefer to have one single material applied to all facets/sides of the object rather than have to manipulate and work with 5 separate ones for such a basic shape, however, this works 100% and addresses the source of the problem thus I'd like to close this out.

Example:

[image: Keep these 5 mats to protect the rendering capabilities of the object imported from Photoshop]

If I find further information regarding how to simplify the object's materials into a single mat, I will post that in a new question and link it here.